# Android wrap_content does not wrap

Tags: android, xml

Newbie Android programmer here. I'm making a xml layout with an EditText whose width should change to fit the text inside--text can be changed either by the user or programatically. I find that when the text exceeds 4 characters, the EditText stops expanding and keeps the excess characters offscreen.
Here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.appname.MainActivity" >

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/seekbar1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textview2"
    android:ems="10"
    android:imeActionLabel="Done"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:text="@string/NaN" />

    //Other objects...

</RelativeLayout>
```

Reading the documentation on wrap_content, I thought it would do what I wanted. Am I mistaken? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You have written android:layout_height="wrap_content". As I understand, you want the width expandable, not the height...

Comment: y cant u use android:singleLine="true" to ur edittext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIrst of all you have fixed the width of edittext

android:layout_width="100dp" this should be changed to wrap_content.

Secondly even if you do that it will not work because wrap content does not work like that. If you have to change the size of EditText dynamically you will have to extend the class TextWatcher and override the method ontextchanged() or afterTextChanged() . In this method you will have to dynamically assign the width attribute based on characters typed.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that...
If I set the initial text to a placeholder of the correct length, will wrap_content do the trick? E.g. if I know the dynamically set text will be of length 6, and I make the initial text "NNNNNN", will it fit?

Comment: You want to change it dynamically so I dont think it would work ..try it and let me know too. Btw pls mark my answer if it helped.. I'll get 20 points if you do :)